# Looking for the ability to create multiple SSID

Tags: home-networking, wireless-access-point

My problem is this:
I am looking for a home-grade or Soho solution to allow me to provision multiple SSID's on one single **router** or **AP**. (5 or more SSID's)

While I'm **not** looking for a specific model or shopping recommendations, I am interested in the **performance** characteristics & experiences people have had with different vendors & model series.

I'm not interested in any of the models that allow one main SSID and one guest SSID (like the Linksys small business AP's)

What access points out there would allow the user to configure multiple SSID's?

I understand that the more SSID beacon's in the air on the same radio and channel the more performance will degrade.

Comment: Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead of asking what to buy, try asking how to find out what suits your needs.

Comment: @Ramhound - GO ahead and edit it as you see fit.  I have seen tons of questions at SuperUser asking for HW help.  I don't understand why I am being scolded by you!

Comment: I am not scolding you.  I am informing you that, your question here at SuperUser is out of scope, I simply failed to mention that a hardware recommendation SE community exists.  Your question isn’t asking for hardware help, you are looking for a product recommendation, I yield editing your question to someone else.  My first comment was a copy and paste of the close reason I selected.  Since I can’t help you, I will yield to somebody else, to handle this situation from here on in.  My apologies for wasting your time.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - I have no thoughts on the matter.  Like I said earlier, I am yielding to other community members, if this question is reopened, then the comments should be flagged so they can be cleaned up.

Comment: All I wanted was a simple answer! Jeez... Someone... please delete this question.  No one will dare answer my question now with all this pollution.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart - Thank you sir.  I will definitely check it out.  I really appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Routers with 5GHz band support different SSID from 2.4GHz SSID